# PrimeFaces tooltip position

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The structure of jsf page:

```
<h:form style="float:left">
...
</h:form>

<div style="float: left; width: 350px">
    ...
    <p:rating id="present" value="#{ph.currentProduct.present}" readonly="true" />
    <p:tooltip for="present" value="..." />
</div>

<h:form class="detail_buy_button">
...
</h:form>
```

What defines the position of tooltip-box? The code does not contains special styles for `p:tooltip` but the tooltip element appears at the x-position of `detail_buy_button`. There is a screenshot for details.
[image]

Comment: Give the rating a border and see where the **right** side ends (or use a browser developer tool)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to style the native Primefaces tooltip, but one option is to use the tooltip component from [Primefaces Extensions](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/tooltip/customizedTooltips.jsf)

**namespace:**

`xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"`

**usage:**

```
    <p:rating id="present" ../>
    <pe:tooltip value="test" for="present"
                myPosition="top left"
                atPosition="bottom right"/>
```

> **myPosition:**
>
> The corner of the tooltip to position in relation to the target element. 
>   Default value is 'top left'.
>
> **atPosition:**
>
> The corner of the target element to position the tooltips corner at. Default value is 'bottom right'.

Comment: This options actually hides the `rating` element. From the other side, using panelGrin was the solution in my case.